# Inserting to TYPE Table is so slow

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a USER DEFINE TABLE TYPE that stores more than 100K rows, now when I try to insert 100k records the insertion of data is very slow. It takes me 1 minute before the insertion is finish. Any idea how to make insertion fast?

```
   --USER DEFINE TABLE TYPE
               CREATE TYPE [dbo].[BigIntegerList] AS TABLE(
                    [ID] [bigint] NULL
                )
                GO

    --sample query    
            DECLARE
            @Data   dbo.BigIntegerList 

            insert into @Data   values(1824953)
            insert into @Data   values(1824954)
            insert into @Data   values(1824955)
            insert into @Data   values(1824956)
            insert into @Data   values(1824996)
            insert into @Data   values(1824997)
            insert into @Data   values(1824998)
            insert into @Data   values(1824999)
            insert into @Data   values(1825000)
            insert into @Data   values(1825001)
            insert into @Data   values(1825002)
            insert into @Data   values(1825003)
            insert into @Data   values(1825004)
            insert into @Data   values(1825005)
            insert into @Data   values(1825006)
            insert into @Data   values(1825007)


        select * from @Data
```

Comment: Why are you using a table datatype?

Comment: I am using this in SP to pass the list of values from the .NET server side code

Comment: When you get your `BigIntegerList` into the DB, are you manipulating any indexed fields with it?

Comment: Are you inserting 100k rows in loop? Can't you change this to one insert?

Comment: the insertion query is the sample above. it's not a one go.

Comment: Phil Walton- No, I am using it as is. there is no manipulation of indexed fields

Comment: Is your Temp DB size on disk too large for the drive? Are there any other queries running while you are doing the insert?

Comment: 100K rows in one minute is 1.66K/second, or 1 row per 1.66 microseconds. That doesn't sound too bad to me.

Comment: Thinking about it, this operation is likely to be memory limited. How much memory is available to SQL server? Does the memory it uses increase doing this operation? Does it swap out other processes during it?

Comment: @simonatrcl Just what about that operation is memory limited?

Answer (score 1):

Why not tag this .NET?

For insert speed use TVP
[maximizing-performance-with-table-valued-parameters](http://www.dbdelta.com/maximizing-performance-with-table-valued-parameters/)

Even if not TVP at least pass multiple values
    values (1824953), (1824954)
About 800 at a time

And does it really need to be bigint?

Comment: Yeah, because the value is incrementing and it will go bigger than usual